# Range variable VLookup issue

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

```
Sub lookup()


Dim wsbreakup As Worksheet
Set wsbreakup = Workbooks("Invoice Breakup Working January 2022.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim filepathpreviousmonth, filenamepreviousmonth As String
filepathpreviousmonth = InputBox("Copy paste the path of previous month")
filenamepreviousmonth = InputBox("Copy Paste the file name of previous month")

Workbooks.Open filepathpreviousmonth & "\" & filenamepreviousmonth

Dim wspreviousmonthlabor As Worksheet
Set wspreviousmonthlabor = Workbooks(filenamepreviousmonth & ".xlsx").Worksheets(1)

lstrw = wsbreakup.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = wspreviousmonthlabor.Range("C")

wsbreakup.Range("D5").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],myrange,1,FALSE)"

End Sub
```

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is within a `String` it is just text and VBA cannot see it as a variable. Therefore you need to concatenate it with `&`.

```
wsbreakup.Range("D5").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2]," & myrange & ",1,FALSE)"
```

Also if `myrange` is a `Range` object you need to use `myrange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)` to get the address of the range which you need for the formula.

Also `Set myrange = wspreviousmonthlabor.Range("C")` should throw an error because `"C"` is no valid address for a range. Either it needs a row number like `"C1"` or if you mean the entire column it needs to be `"C:C"` to be a valid address.